# how can i increase the sizeof the video using the code below

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have written a code for playing and pausing a video but when I run the code, it appears small on the screen. However, I want to increase the size of the video.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <body>
        <div class="col-md-10 canvas"></div>
        <center>
            <button onclick="playVid()" type="button">
                Play Video
            </button>
            <button onclick="pauseVid()" type="button">
                Pause Video
            </button>
            <br>
            <video id="myVideo" width="320" height="176">
                <source src="./audios/lp_gateway.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                <source src="./audios/lp_gateway.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </center>

        <script> 
            var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");

            // for playing 
            function playVid() { 
                vid.play(); 
            }

            // for pausing
            function pauseVid() { 
                vid.pause(); 
            } 
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<video id="myVideo" width="320" height="176">` <===

Comment: Please accept the answer below if it helped you or add more details if it didn't achieve the result you wanted. From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/27033246).

Comment: Also there are probably missing some links or scripts. Where did the `col-md-10` class come from?

Comment: col-md-10 is for the controlling the size of canvas

Comment: it has worked for me

Comment: So why didn't you accept it if it worked?

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the size of the video container, you can increase it by:

1. Increasing the width and height values in:

```
<video id="myVideo" width="1280" height="720">
```

2. Removing the width and height from the  tag and specifying it in the css:

```
#myVideo {
    width: 1280px;
    height: 720px;
}
```

If you are referring to the size of the video being played inside the container, you can do it via css, just do the step #2 above and add `object-fit: cover;` to it:

```
#myVideo {
    width: 1280px;
    height: 720px;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```